# php exec() error values

Tags: php, exec

I have two subsequent exec commands.  The first executes without issue the second however is throwing an error:

```
exec('/usr/bin/pdftk A='. trim($original) .' cat A1 output '. trim($onepage), $output, $error);
var_dump($output); var_dump($error);

exec('/usr/bin/pdftk '. trim($onepage) .' background watermark.pdf output '. trim($modified), $output, $error);
var_dump($output); var_dump($error);
```

The first produces:

```
array(0) { } int(0)
```

The second:

```
array(0) { } int(1)
```

The permissions on the php script and directories are exactly the same. I've tried ecaping the exec command using [escapeshellargs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) with no luck either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your error is, but I would recommend that you reduce some of the background noise so that you can see the problem easier.  What I mean by this is the following...

Take

```
exec('/usr/bin/pdftk A='. trim($original) .' cat A1 output '. trim($onepage), $output, $error);
var_dump($output); var_dump($error);

exec('/usr/bin/pdftk '. trim($onepage) .' background watermark.pdf output '. trim($modified), $output, $error);
var_dump($output); var_dump($error);
```

And do

```
$command1 = '/usr/bin/pdftk A='. trim($original) .' cat A1 output '. trim($onepage);
$command2 = '/usr/bin/pdftk '. trim($onepage) .' background watermark.pdf output '. trim($modified);

exec($command1, $output, $error);
var_dump($output); var_dump($error);
echo $command1;

exec($command2, $output, $error);
var_dump($output); var_dump($error); 
echo $command2;
```

That way you can cut and paste the output of the command issued onto the unix command line, and perhaps get a better view of what is going on at the unix level.

Comment: The error is that the second command is not processed at all and the var_dump() of the error returns 1 which means there was an error.

Comment: it looks like i can only run one exec() per script.

Comment: Have you try `system` instead: http://id2.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php ?

Comment: yes i tried system as well. subsequent calls to pdftk were an issue.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was the following:

```
   $descriptorspec = array(
      0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
      1 => array("pipe", "w"));
   proc_open('/usr/bin/pdftk '. trim($onepage) .' background watermark.pdf output '. trim($modified), $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```